# Pause video file download via JS?

Tags: javascript, http, video, download

Is it possible to pause a video file download (I assume an http get request) and resume it at a later time?

My website ajax requests all it's pages and I'd need to pause a video download if the user needs to download something else (to stop too much bandwidth being used).

Scenario:
 - User visits webpage
 - Video starts downloading
 - User interacts with another part of the webpage
 - Video stops downloading
 - Another file starts downloading (initiated by the user)
 - Once file download complete, video download starts where it left off

---

I already don't think this is possible due to the little amount I can find on this subject.
My colleagues also suggest it's not possible.

Comment: So after some digging, I think the best approach is to split the file into chunks and build a player which can play these smaller chunks in succession.