# How to pause and resume a download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, download-manager

I'm trying to create a downloader. My biggest concern is how should I pause a download.

I am showing a progress bar of download, I want to pause it when it's 30% and wants to resume it after any UI response.

Any idea how should I do it?

Using **javascript, AJAX call (Any js plugin will also do)**

Comment: [I posted a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362077/pause-video-file-download-via-js) about 3 years ago. Considering I have had no answers in that time, it's safe to assume it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks, man. I was just checking if there is any way around.

Comment: Split the file and combine it on the client side?

Comment: It's definitely possible, check mega.co.nz they have that feature for at least 3 years; they seem to use the FileSystem API