# How to download in multipart and merge files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, electron, multipart

I'm working on a download manager for electron js project which requires downloading large files.

The [multipart-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipart-download) package unfortunately does not support pausing or cancelling downloads.
Are there any other solution which uses Fetch or Axios or anything with pause and cancellation supports?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using asynchronous functions? You can do a lot with JS Promise..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I'm not sure Promises can help with downloading single in multple parts

Comment: video and large zip files

Comment: I have mainly worked with blobs but should be fairly similar to split video into chunks. Ergo:        
   `createChunks = (file,cSize/* cSize should be byte 1024*1 = 1KB */) => {
   let startPointer = 0;
   let endPointer = file.size;
   let chunks = [];
   while(startPointer<endPointer){
    let newStartPointer = startPointer+cSize;
    chunks.push(file.slice(startPointer,newStartPointer));
    startPointer = newStartPointer;
   }
   return chunks;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Useful info to write your own downloader implementation:
[HTML5 File API downloading file from server and saving it in sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752984/html5-file-api-downloading-file-from-server-and-saving-it-in-sandbox)
So you need to download the file via XMLHttpRequest, with HTML5 FileAPI and [streamsaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsaver) you can save it into client file sandbox. For pausing, you should abort the request and make another with Content-Range headers ([Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)). Of course, they also should be supported on the backend side.

Comment: The descriptions says it is for uploads

Comment: @SaiKrishna Oops. I read it inattentively. In this case it seems you will have to write your own implementation. There are few dead npm packages, but I'm not sure that using it is a good idea (su-downloader3-enhance , cordova-plugin-pause-resume-download). I'm not aware of stable and popular implementation and according to StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507608/how-to-pause-and-resume-a-download-file)- nobody does. But it's possible if you have around a week to write your own implementation for both sides- client and server.